# Why are lyophillic sols uncharged and lyophobic sols charged?

Tags: surface-chemistry

Gums, resins, glue, gelatin starch are uncharged and lyophillic where as metal sulphides and hydroxides are charged and lyophobic.

Right after studying o-chem this seemed quite contradictory as polar solvents are supposed to dissolve polar solutes and non polar solvents non polar solutes.

Why does this not work for sols, why are polar/charged compounds lyophobic but uncharged lyophillic?

Comment: I am late but can u try adding more tags ? I have the same doubt